# jQuery mobile checkbox not recognized after cloning

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, checkbox

I'm currently working on a project that uses jQuery, jQuery mobile and jQuery Template.

My problem is, that jQuery Mobile doesn't recognize the already styled checkboxes if they were created by jQuery Template. When I call `.checkboxradio( 'refresh' )` I get an error:

`cannot call methods on checkboxradio prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'`

Alas, due to the existing project, which I cannot recreate from the base, there is no way around the jQuery Template.
Anyways, jQuery Template is not essential to reproduce the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/robbash/PRGsF/

So after cloning the jQM checkbox seems to be kind of broken and I'd like to fix it, but I don't know how...

Any suggestions? What does jQM need to recognize it as checkbox?

**EDIT:**

```
.checkboxradio().checkboxradio( 'refresh' )
```

doesn't work:

http://screencast.com/t/ue0C6jFu

http://screencast.com/t/uq3FnWAsh

Can I somehow revert the jQM styles to get the "raw" item and start with it again?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not possible to work with this approach (as another mysteriously disappeared answer stated; thanks though).

My workaround now is to prevent jQM UI creating until the jQuery Template engine did its job and `.trigger( 'create' )` then.